# Automorphisms of a semidirect product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Is there any way to compute $Aut(H \rtimes K)$? I don't know either how to compute the simplest ones, like semidirect product of two cyclic groups. Any hint, books to read or articles about this theme? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many papers one can find by simply googling the title of this post.

Comment: In a direction opposite to Lee's answer but yielding the same conclusion ("there is no general pattern to such a computation"): let $F_2$ be free of rank 2, $N$ a normal subgroup such that $F/N$ is infinite cyclic; then $N$ is free of infinite rank. The group $Aut(F)$ is somewhat unrelated to this decomposition; $Aut(N)$ (which is uncountable) plays no role, and so does $Aut(G/N)$ which is cyclic of order 2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any general pattern to such a computation.

For example, direct products are a special case of semidirect products. So, just to have a concrete example, any general method would have to deal with the unexpected complexities of 
$$Aut(\mathbb{Z}^3 \times \mathbb{Z}^7) = Aut(\mathbb{Z}^{10}) = GL(10,\mathbb{Z})
$$

Comment: Is there something on finite groups?

Comment: One can do the same kinds of constructions in finite groups, with similar unexpected complexities:  replace $\mathbb{Z}$ in my example with $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime number $p$ and you get $GL(10,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: For finite groups there are general results. There is a description of the automorphism group of $H \times K$, assuming that $H$ and $K$ have no direct factor in common. This is in terms of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$, and the sets of homomorphisms $H \rightarrow Z(K)$ and $K \rightarrow Z(H)$. Then for $G$ indecomposable I think we can also describe $\operatorname{Aut}(G \times G \times \cdots \times G)$ in terms of $G$.

Comment: $GL(n,\mathbb{F}_P)$ is not so complex to identify, as it is a group. I'm asking if, for example, there is a way to describe $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_q)$.